# User Login Excel

Tags: excel, vba

What I would like to do is create a user login and password to get into an excel file.  Meaning, when they click the file to open they immediately get taken to the login sheet I have and if the password is wrong the get denied access and the book closes. This is the code that I have so far which works while you are in excel.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim UserName As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim ThisCell As Range
    Dim c As Long
    For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Sh.Name <> "WELCOME SCREEN" Then
            Sh.Visible = Sheet4
        End If
    Next Sh
    UserName = InputBox("Please enter your user name.")
    Password = InputBox("Please enter password.")
    For Each ThisCell In Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A2:A" & Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row)
        If UCase(ThisCell.Value) = UCase(UserName) And UCase(ThisCell.Offset(,  1).Value) = UCase(Password) Then
            MsgBox "Access Granted"
            For c = 2 To 4
                'This is the number of sheets from C1 to E1
                If ThisCell.Offset(, c).Value <> "" Then
                    Sheets(Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(1, c + 1).Value).Visible = xlSheetVisible
                End If
            Next c
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next ThisCell
    MsgBox "Access Denied"
    ThisWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Where Sheet4 is a hidden sheet that contains all of the usernames and passwords. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this all occurring on a form, and is the form's modal property set to to true?  [check out the best answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282021/vba-thisworkbook-close-does-not-close-this-workbook)

Comment: Yes, it is happening in a form or module that I wrote. However, I am not sure where to find the modal property.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on excel macro for security.  If I wanted to get in I would just disable macros and this wouldn't run.  You also have everyone's password stored within the sheet so it would be easy enough unhide the sheet and grab all usernames and passwords (which people tend to reuse for multiple applications).

Comment: Look into file permissions and workbook protection. Don't roll your own security, you're wasting your time. And instead of looping, use `INDEX`/`MATCH` worksheet functions to lookup the password... just exactly why you'd have every user's name and password in plain text on a "hidden" worksheet (that any legit user can unhide, copy to another workbook and upload to GitHub) is beyond me though.

Comment: That said, I've no idea what your question is. Look into [VBA UserForm Best Practices](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/5351/user-forms/19036/best-practices#t=201705192021044153001) to avoid implementing the whole logic in the form's code-behind and hit the issue @JimmySmith mentioned.

Comment: like Mat's Mug I am not sure what your question is - you have a working macro that asks for user and password after it actually opens the file, so you want something that would first ask and then open the file? (which I doubt is possible). Just as gtwebb wrote relying on macro for security is dodgy - to prevent opening by disabling macros you can use xlVeryHidden property and hide all sheets before every save + protect your vba project, but there will still be way to get inside...

Comment: There's no reason for `Sheet(4).Visible`, which would make all your user ID/Passwords visible to everyone who opens it. You can access `Sheet(4)` even while it's hidden.

Comment: @FreeMan I can't even begin to enumerate every issue with this code. That's a job for [codereview.se]. The answer you posted is the only reasonable answer to give this question.

Comment: Don't get us wrong, there's nothing quite like the excitement of getting some code working to do something nifty, then you bring it here and get that miserable feeling when it gets shot full of holes. Unfortunately, this just isn't the right way to do what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of rolling your own security in a macro which is easily defeated (as documented the the comments on your OP), why don't you just take advantage of the built in Excel password protection that is available from the Save dialogue box? (Click the `Tools` drop down, just in case it wasn't explicitly clear)

[image]

You can then distribute the password to those who need to know. If there is a high likelihood of people passing the password to those who shouldn't have it, change it regularly...

There may well be fragility in the Microsoft password facility (I'm not aware of any, some Googling aught to tell you), but I'm pretty certain it's more secure than your proposal.

Comment: That. Sadly the OP isn't learning about UserForms (which I believe might have been the underlying unwritten question here), but big huge upvote for "don't roll your own" and showing the *actual* way to password-protect an Excel workbook.

Comment: @user1274820 - I'll point you at [security.se] for 1,001 reasons not to roll your own security. However, if one were to call an existing encryption routine... maybe. Of course, setting permissions on the file and/or the directory in which it's stored might be easier than all the above.

Comment: Currently, the 40-bit key RC4 protection used in Office 97–2003 can typically be bypassed with password hacking software. The 128-bit key AES protection employed in newer Office 2007–2010 remains secure.

Comment: @user1274820 what you break in a split-second with a simple macro is the VBE "protection" that locks the VBA project. Not saying Excel workbooks are uncrackable, but since the .xlsx format came along, encryption and security are very acceptable IMO.

Comment: Yea, after doing some reading it appears that newer formats do use 128 AES which is good. Back in the day zip password protection and excel password protection was garbage. Glad to see that is no longer the case.

Comment: Though here is the macro that supposedly works on Excel 2010. It may just be to unprotect a single sheet though?
 I'm not sure. https://uknowit.uwgb.edu/page.php?id=28850

Comment: If the data contained in said Excel sheet is _that_ important, Excel's built in protection should probably be the last layer of many to protect the file.

Comment: I had a coworker using excel macros to keep track of QA scores and statistics - These scores were used in reviews and determined your raises. He used a password to protect the view stats code, but it was all there and it was very easy to go in and change my score if I wanted to. I moved the whole thing to an internal web database and it's much more secure.

Comment: If the sensitive *data* is contained in an Excel sheet, there's the problem: move the data elsewhere (a secured, Windows-authenticated SQL Server for example), and have the Excel workbook *query* it as needed, and wipe everything on close.

Comment: ^ This is what I was getting at - if you have to store it locally, encryption. If you have a server you can use, query the data - don't store it locally.